# erro ao Salvar no banco JSF+JPA & Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsf-2.2, xhtml

Boa tarde estou fazendo um cadastro com JSF , e quando tento salvar o usuário no banco acontece esse erro , porem ja adicionei todos os jars na pasta lib tomcat , e ja foi verificado que não existe nenhum jar igual ou com versão diferente para não dar conflito, fiz o teste com a classe de persistência e conseguir cria tabela funcionário, então acredito que não seja esse  o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc configurou o context dessa aplicação?

Comment: amigo so configurei persistence.xml , com dados para conexão com banco , o pom.xml com as dependências e o web.xml

Comment: para complementar configurei também as variáveis de ambiente para executar o tomcat , ta funcionando , chama a pagina normalmente , erro acontece quando clico no botão para salvar